# Creating a PHP session variable based on one value pulled from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, e-commerce

This is for a school project where I am creating an ecommerce website that has a rewards system implemented. I am using PHPMyAdmin to connect to a MySQL server.

Basically, I want to create a session variable based on how many reward points the customer *currently logged in* has. In other words, the value of the session variable would be equivalent to the number of rewards points shown in the specific customer's record within the MySQL database. If the value is NULL, I would set the variable = to zero.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This will not be accurate over time, if the end user gains points after the query, it will not update the session. Why not just query it as part of the User model? This seems overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Utilising a session here would not guarantee data integrity: if points are increased or decreased after the query, your session will not update.

Instead, [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) your tables together and attach it to your User model (MVC).

Example (assuming your tables):

```
$stmt = (new PDO('...', ['...']))->prepare('SELECT u.id, u.column, r.points FROM users u INNER JOIN rewards r ON r.id = u.ud WHERE u.id = ?');
$stmt->execute([(int) $someUserId]);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Now you can use your User model like normal:

```
$user->column; // Normal
$user->points  // Joint Table
```

[See an example of how to construct it on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/3WrMs)